# page content displaying upon menu bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing a kind of problem that maybe I can't properly tell you guys about.  I am working with a management system where my menu bar is fixed to display the whole page.  meaning the menu bar is always showed.  But the problem is-->my other page content displayed upon my menu bar,that is occurred.please show this pic below->[image]

look my search box is displaying upon my menu bar.  That is happening when I scroll my page.
First my menu bar is inside my body tag.  the for selving this problem is took it to the head tag->but still problem is occurring.
code->

```
<!-- top navigation bar -->
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%" class="w3-container w3-teal">
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-container">
    <li class="w3-right" ><a href="destroy.php">Log Out</a></li>
    <li class="w3-right w3-dropdown-hover w3-hover-orange">
      <a class="w3-hover-orange" >Options<i class="fa fa-caret-down">    </i></a>
      <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
        <a href="changepassword.php">change password</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="w3-right" ><a href="userprofile.php">User Profile</a></li>
    <li class="w3-right" ><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="w3-right" ><button class="w3-btn w3-black" id="sgo">Go</button></li>
    <li class="w3-right" ><input type="text" class="w3-input" id="text-search" placeholder="Search.."></li>
    </ul>
    </div> 
    <!-- end of top navigation bar -->
```

and body->

```
<body class="w3-theme">
<?php include 'pageSideNavigationBar.php'; ?>
<section class="w3-row-padding w3-theme" style="margin-left:165px;" id="main-content">
  <div id="guts">
    <a style=" margin-left: 88%;width: 11%;border-radius: 2px;" class="w3-btn-block w3-green w3-section w3-padding" onclick="$('#addABatch').show()">Add A Batch</a><br>
    <!-- TABLE TO SHOW THE DATA -->
    <div class="w3-container">
      <p>Available Batch details....</p>
      <table id="myTable" class="display" data-page-length="25" data-order="[[ 1, &quot;asc&quot; ]]" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Batch Code</th>
            <th>Course Name</th>
            <th data-orderable="false">Batch Starting Date</th>
            <th>Faculty Name</th>
            <th>Room Number</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Routine</th>
            <th>Delete Batch</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
```

and closing tags.  sorry can't give full code->>>>

what is the problem.  why this is happening.....

Answer (score 0):

add this to your navbar style

```
z-index: 99999;
```

it should work

Comment: where i should add it->in content of the page style or page top navigation bar....

Comment: great!, in case you ask what it does, it orders elements on top of each others the element how has the biggest z-index is displayed first.